# How to get non Hi-Res image in Skitch?

Tags: skitch

I have a Macbook Pro Retina.  When I capture an image in Skitch, it is always twice the size.  I shrink them back down via Preview for social media.

Is there some way to make Skitch capture in non Hi-Res mode?  Or is there a tool that can quickly reduce these images by 1/2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of re-sizing apps on the Mac App Store that will allow you to drag an image onto a Dock icon and such. "[Resize This](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/resize-this/id614530344?ls=1&mt=12)" was the first one I found via search.